# Lining up two separate Divs in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to line up two lists one which contains .jpg files, in a div, and the other are text files in another list.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
    .left{height:auto; float:left;}
    .right{height:auto; float:right;}

</style>
<body>
<br>
<br>
<?php
    $files = scandir('files');
    sort($files); // this does the sorting
    foreach($files as $file){
        $extension = pathinfo($file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if($extension == 'jpg')
                echo'<br><div class="left">'.$file .'</div>';
    }

    $files2 = scandir('files');
    sort($files2); // this does the sorting
    foreach($files2 as $file2){
        $extension2 = pathinfo($file2,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if($extension2 == 'txt')
                echo'<br><div class="left">'.$file2 .'</div>';
    }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to line them up in the middle of the browser window, like such:

```
                       test.jpg  test.txt
                       test2.jpg test2.txt
                       here.jpg  here.txt
```

Instead the output I'm getting is this:

```
test.jpg
test2.jpg
here.jpg
test.txt
test2.txt
here.txt
```

Even though I'm using float left. I tried using float:right for the text files but that just puts the div on the right, with again the wrong height.

I tried adding `margin:auto;`,`display inline-block;`

But none of those seem to help.

A markup of sorts...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
    .left{float:left; height:auto;}
    .right{float:left; height:auto;}

</style>
<body>
<br>
<br>

            test.jpg test.txt<br>
            test2.jpg test2.txt<br>
            here.jpg  here.txt<br>

</body>
</html>
```

I need to use php because I need to scan the files in a certain directory, this is how it should look like (where the file lists are in the middle of the screen).

Comment: Post the rendered HTML in your question please -- the PHP is irrelevant here.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I'm new to this sorry.

Comment: Add your markup as similar how u added the code

Comment: So add a Jsfiddle?

Comment: No jsfiddle please since once they get removed people with a similar question might not understand your question. Just paste it into your question in a code block. A fiddle might be a bonus for better understanding but not the only resource.

Comment: I don't fully understand what I'm so posed to paste, I'm working in a text editor and this is the only code i have..

Comment: Remove the php stuff and add a blank markup of what you want it to look like after the php generated its content. This is the markup you should paste (for example look at the answers below)

Comment: So a picture? of What it should look like? Don't I already have that? In the files I'm listing which are indented. THe line :"I want to line them up in the middle of the browser window, like SUCH"

Comment: No like the php code you posted but without the php. Just HTML and CSS since these are the only things that matter here. PHP is irrelevant for your specific question.

Comment: I've updated it, php is certainly relevant because that gives me the files I need to print, I can't hardcode filenames...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also consider using flex for this

check the following snippet

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container div {
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg" height="20px" width="20px"></img>
  </div>

  <div>
    text1
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg" height="20px" width="20px"></img>
  </div>
  <div>
    text2
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg" height="20px" width="20px"></img>
  </div>
  <div>
    text3
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the 2 divs inside a parent div such as:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="left"></div>
   <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

**And also make sure you have the classes of divs right as now there are 2 left classes**

[image: screenshot of jsfiddle]
[Link to this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j8L4h8za/)

Comment: add a link to your fiddle for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to float them left and give them your desired width. This is the way most simple grid systems behave.

```css
.left {
  background: #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.right {
  background: #666;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  div left
</div>
<div class="right">
  div right
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for my code, still displays them on the same vertical line.

Comment: Can you post your HTML then?

Comment: I've posted HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap everything in a div tag. Putting them both in another Div tag will allow you to use float left and float right properly.

something like:

```
<div id='wrap'>

<div id='left'>test.jpg</div>
<div id='right'>test.txt </div>

</div>
```

make sure the wrap is styled to be big enough to hold the other 2 divs side by side. (i.e. if the wrap width is 1000px, then the other divs should be under 1000px when added. this can be avoided by using percentages on the inner tags.)

the CSS should look something like:

```
#wrap {
width:1000px;
}

#left{
float:left;
width:50%;
}

#right{
float:right;
width:50%;
}
```

For the putting it into the middle, you just need to add:

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
display:block;
```

into the 'wrap' CSS. i.e.

```
#wrap {
width:1000px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
display:block;
    }
```

I don't see a `<head>` on your code. could that be the problem?